# Why does the execute() method of ExecutorService returned from Executors utility class could not terminate naturally

Tags: java, currency, threadpoolexecutor, java-threads

As we know, the `java.util.concurrent.Executors` contains many methods such as

- `newCachedThreadPool`
- `newFixedThreadPool`
- `newScheduledThreadPool`
- `newSingleThreadExecutor`
- `newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor`

  They return `ExecutorService`, which contains the `execute(Runnable task)` method. However, when calling the `execute(Runnable task)` of `ExecutorService` returned from the aforementioned *factory methods*, it could only terminate by calling `shutdown()` or `shutdownNow()`

For instance, if we add the following code to the `main` method,

```
ExecutorService e = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();
e.execute(() -> system.out.println("test"));
```

the calling the the main program will never terminate as the `shutdown()` or `shutdownNow()` is not called. So a program containing the following snippet in *main* will terminate

```
ExecutorService e = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();
e.execute(() -> system.out.println("test"));
e.shutdown();
```

However, some subclasses of `ExecutorService` such as the one returned by calling `Executors.newWorkStealingPool` or the `ForkJoinPool` can terminate without calling `shutdown()` or `shutdownNow()`

So my **QUESTION** is: **why does the `execute()` of the `ExecutorService` returned from the aforementioned *factory methods* starting with "new" not terminate without calling `shutdown()` or `shutdownNow()` from the design point of view?**

Comment: Can not understand what you are asking

Comment: Those factory methods return ExecutorService objects, whi are not the same thing as the execution submitted to them using `.execute`. Why do you need to compare those two?

Comment: Can you add the code of the `Runnable` you are using ?

Comment: @ErnestKiwele I would like to know why the returned `ExecutorService`, mostly is the `ThreadPoolExecutor`, was designed in such way

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Briefly about java threads: there are two types of threads - daemon and non-daemon. The program terminates when all of its non-daemon threads have finished execution. Daemon threads can only run as long the program is running and do not block termination, e.g. [garbage collector](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5218848/is-garbage-collector-a-daemon-thread). When a java program starts all of its threads except the main thread are daemon.

`newSingleThreadExecutor()` and its [`defaultThreadFactory()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Executors.html#defaultThreadFactory()) create non-daemon threads. Which kinda makes sense - you're creating a pool of *threads* that wait for work, it should be your explicit intention to shut it down.

ForkJoinPool, on the other hand, abstracts you from the underlying thread pool. So it can use daemon threads, as it is generally your intention to wait for task execution anyways.

Comment: It would be nice to show an example using CompleteableFuture:

    CompletableFuture.runAsync(() -> System.out.println("test"));

Answer (score 0):

Rui, the answer for why your example hangs is simple. By default, the threads in the ExecutorService are non-daemon threads and a Java program won't exit as long as there are non-daemon threads running.  If you don't want this behavior all you need to do is define a ThreadFactory that creates daemon threads, like this:

```
public class Test {
    static ThreadFactory mThreadFactory = new ThreadFactory() {
        public Thread newThread(Runnable r) {
            Thread t = new Thread(r);
            t.setDaemon(true);
            return t;
        }
    };

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ExecutorService e = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor(mThreadFactory);
        e.execute(new Runnable() { public void run() { System.out.println("test"); } });
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your reply. Good for me to review the daemon threads. However, if we do so, I am afraid that even the program running the `ExecutorService` terminated, the generated daemon threads are still running in the background, isn't it?