# How does a program run after main() exits?

Tags: java, twitter, twitter4j

I have written a program that uses the twitter stream to write tweets in Realtime to a `File` via a `BufferedWriter`.
But the bufferedWriter does not write the text until i call the `close()` method at the end of the main function.

Now, when i run the program, the file is closed at first and then the tweets start coming.  How does this thing work after main exits???

Here is the Code:

```
package analytics;


import twitter4j.*;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
```

public final class Trial_Filters {

```
static String Tweet;
static FileWriter output;
static BufferedWriter writer;



public static void main(String[] args) throws TwitterException,IOException {



    if (args.length < 1) {
        System.out.println("Usage: java twitter4j.examples.PrintFilterStream [follow(comma separated numerical user ids)] [track(comma separated filter terms)]");
        System.exit(-1);
    }


    output= new FileWriter("Log.txt");
    writer=new BufferedWriter(output);




    StatusListener listener = new StatusListener() {
        public void onStatus(Status status) {
            StringBuilder temp;


            //System.out.print("<sta>"); // Start Status -- helps for parsing two lines tweet;<sta> and </sta> used as tweet delimiters
            temp=new StringBuilder("<sta>");

            if(status.isRetweet())
                temp.append("%");//System.out.print("%"); // easier to identify ReTweets

            //System.out.println("@" + status.getUser().getScreenName() + " - " + status.getText());
            temp.append("@" + status.getUser().getScreenName() + " - " + status.getText());

            //System.out.print("</sta>");   //End Status
            temp.append("</sta>");

            Tweet=temp.toString();

            this.add_to_Log();

        }


        private void add_to_Log(){
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            try{
            output= new FileWriter("Log.txt");
            writer=new BufferedWriter(output);

            writer.write(Tweet);
            System.out.println(Tweet);
            }
            catch(Exception e)
            {
                System.out.println(e);
            }

        }


        public void onDeletionNotice(StatusDeletionNotice statusDeletionNotice) {
            System.out.println("Got a status deletion notice id:" + statusDeletionNotice.getStatusId());
        }

        public void onTrackLimitationNotice(int numberOfLimitedStatuses) {
            System.out.println("Got track limitation notice:" + numberOfLimitedStatuses);
        }

        public void onScrubGeo(long userId, long upToStatusId) {
            System.out.println("Got scrub_geo event userId:" + userId + " upToStatusId:" + upToStatusId);
        }

        public void onException(Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    };

    TwitterStream twitterStream = new TwitterStreamFactory().getInstance();
    twitterStream.addListener(listener);
    ArrayList<Long> follow = new ArrayList<Long>();
    ArrayList<String> track = new ArrayList<String>();
    for (String arg : args) {
        if (isNumericalArgument(arg)) {
            for (String id : arg.split(",")) {
                follow.add(Long.parseLong(id));
            }
        } else {
            track.addAll(Arrays.asList(arg.split(",")));
        }
    }
    long[] followArray = new long[follow.size()];
    for (int i = 0; i < follow.size(); i++) {
        followArray[i] = follow.get(i);
    }
    String[] trackArray = track.toArray(new String[track.size()]);

    // filter() method internally creates a thread which manipulates TwitterStream and calls these adequate listener methods continuously.
    twitterStream.filter(new FilterQuery(0, followArray, trackArray));


    try{
        System.out.println("bye");
         writer.close();
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            System.out.println(e);
        }


    }


private static boolean isNumericalArgument(String argument) {
    String args[] = argument.split(",");
    boolean isNumericalArgument = true;
    for (String arg : args) {
        try {
            Integer.parseInt(arg);
        } catch (NumberFormatException nfe) {
            isNumericalArgument = false;
            break;
        }
    }
    return isNumericalArgument;
}
```

}

Comment: Pls provide some code sample.

Comment: The runtime is shutdown after your `main()` function returns. Presumably that's what is triggering the behaviour. But it's hard to say more than that with no code at all.

Comment: You can force the BufferedWriter to write its output with an explicit call to `flush`.  When this happens, the content of the buffer it written to the underlying output stream and the buffered is emptied.

Comment: I hate it when without even understanding the Problem ; the question is down Rated!

Comment: Not your down voter, but that can happen if the question is not complete enough. Often the down voter will rescind the vote once the question has been updated and clarified.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The TwitterStream Object will start a thread, and that thread will call back on the StatusListener. The program will run until there is a thread running, even if the main thread seems to have finished, it waits for all other threads to stop, before the main thread stops, and the program exits.

It does not matter if you close the writer or not on the end of main. The reference of the writer will be rewritten on each call to add_to_log. That means on each new status a new writer gets instantiated, writes out the message into the bufferedwriter.

The following two lines at the beginning of the code are irrelevant:

```
output= new FileWriter("Log.txt");
writer=new BufferedWriter(output);
```

However it would be better to call flush() or close() in add_to_log to make sure everything gets written to disk.

Answer (score 4):

The virtual machine terminates all activity and exits after the last [non-daemon thread ("User Thread") has terminated](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jvms/second_edition/html/Concepts.doc.html#19152) (or some thread invoked `System.exit()`). That last User thread doesn't have to be the *main* thread.

The *tweets* (packets) are sent to a local socket and the socket is only bound as long as the virtual machine is up and running (in case the socket hasn't been closed manually). So the feed may be sending but the computer won't accept the data and the *tweet source* will receive errors.

Comment: I corrected that to say that main finishes when the last non-daemon thread finishes to be correct.

Comment: This is slightly more confusing then it was before. You added non-Java threads to the discussion, right? Processes, that are started by a java application but that are entirely disconnected from the JVM? Then I'd include add your valid comment by talking of "Java Threads".

Comment: No, He is correct, and your answer should specify non-daemon thread.

Comment: Please read up on daemon and non-daemon threads and again modify your answer accordingly: [What is a Daemon Thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2213340/what-is-daemon-thread-in-java), [Thread API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html)

Comment: Initially, the answer was about incoming messages after a jvm has terminated. I didn't want to lecture about threads ;) But anyway, I linked the answer to the JVMS. Ah, and thanks for the downvote ;)

Comment: Down-vote removed with your edit. I think most of us feel that a "lecture on threads" is germane to the original problem.

Answer (score 0):

When you close a program with a bufferedWriter activated, the system triggers the buffered writer to flush its output to whatever endpoint it's hooked up to, be it a file or stdout. Over time, what could be happening, is that documents are arriving on the socket and getting placed into the bufferedwriter, but your the writer just stores them up because you haven't called flush() from the code or the writer threshold for doing a dump hasn't been crossed. When you call close, under the hood, it calls flush and forces the output to dump--even if the program is "closed".