# Java, running external programs

Tags: java

I am trying to write a chatbot. I am still in my startings, but I do have one question.

```
Process proc = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("notepad.exe");
```

This actually makes it impossible to quit my program, unless I quit the notepad. Is it possible to quit the Java program before this notepad has ended?

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is Daemon thread in java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2213340/what-is-daemon-thread-in-java)

Comment: Yes, but it's platform specific and very messy to achieve.

Answer (score 1):

You can run an external program via a separate thread in your program and continue your program logic in your main thread, i.e. a *multi-threaded* application is a good solution.

Comment: Even if the program runs in another thread, I can't quit the program. Does this mean that, if I want to run a big memory-eating program, like games like Skyrim, it's running in the Java application, thus terminating the Java-app process, means terminating the external program?

Answer (score 0):

First destroy the subprocess :

```
Process proc = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("notepad.exe");
proc.destroy();
```

If this doesn't work, get the process id of the process  and  run a different subprocess to run `kill <pid>`

then exit java with `System.exit(0);` or normally.