# How can I do healthchecks between threads?

Tags: java, multithreading, design-patterns, concurrency

I have a process that one of its background threads (`Thread-A`) does a task. If the process hangs/crashes, I want to make sure that the background thread crashes/stops as well (ok for me).

What I mean is I don't want to be in a situation where some of the threads are crashed and so the process essentially is non-functional and that background thread (`Thread-A`) keeps going.

I need to somehow make that thread understand the problem.
Is there a pattern for this? Some kind of health check may be? Still though how can I be sure I don't get the same problem with the health check thread.

Perhaps I am confused on this. Could you please help me out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public class HealthChecker
{
    public final long THRESHOLD = 10000L; // 10 seconds

    private final Map <Thread, Long> lastFineReports =
        new ConcurrentHashMap <Thread, Long> ();

    /**
     * Each thread should call this method periodically.
     */
    public void iAmFine ()
    {
        lastFineReports.put (
            Thread.currentThread (), 
            Long.valueOf (System.currentTimeMillis ()));
    }

    /**
     * Used by whatchdog to know whether everything is OK.
     */
    public boolean isEverythingOK ()
    {
        Long [] timestamps = 
            lastFineReports.
                values ().
                    toArray (new Long [lastFineReports.size ()]);

        long now = System.currentTimeMillis ();
        for (Long t: timestamps)
            if (now - t.longValue () > THRESHOLD)
                return false;

        return true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to look at the `ExecutorService` in `java.util.concurrent`, you can then ask the service to terminate when the main thread exits using `ExecutorService.shutdown()` as long as your background thread is periodic so can be stopped.

Otherwise you need to use an `AtomicBoolean` to signal between threads and tell the background thread to exit when the boolean is false.

Finally, to detect crashes in the first thread use an `UncaughtExceptionHandler` with a callback that signals the background thread to exit.

Of course this can all be avoided by using [daemon threads](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2213340/what-is-daemon-thread-in-java) but that would not allow the background thread to clean up after itself if it gets unexpectedly killed.

Comment: It is not about signaling among threads but healthchecks and understanding that there is a problem.