# Why doesn't onComplete wait for Promise.success in the code in Scala?

Tags: scala

I'm reading about Futures and Promises in Scala and wrote the following code:

```
def printSomething(): Future[String] = {
  val p = Promise[String]
  val sayHello = future {
    Thread.sleep(1000)
    p.success("hello")
  }
  p.future
}

def main(args: Array[String]) {
  val something: Future[String] = printSomething()
  something onComplete {
    case Success(p) => println(p)
  }
}
```

The problem is the `onComplete` callback doesn't `print` anything (unless I debug it).

Wouldn't the `onComplete` have to wait for the `p.success("hello")` in the `printSomething` ?

Comment: I had to write `val sayHello = Future { ... }` to get this to compile.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

My guess is that this has to do with the `ExecutionContext` you are [using daemon threads](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2213348/298389) and thus terminating when your `main` gets past the `onComplete`.  If you add a sleep after the `onComplete`, you should get what you want.  A slightly modified version of your code showing this:

```
import concurrent._
import ExecutionContext.Implicits._

object PromTest {
  def printSomething(): Future[String] = {
    val p = Promise[String]
    val sayHello = future {
      Thread.sleep(1000)
      p.success("hello")
    }
    p.future
  }

  def main(args: Array[String]) {
    val something: Future[String] = printSomething()
    something onComplete {
      case result => println(result)
    }
    Thread.sleep(2000)
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

As other people have stated, your execution terminates before your future has had a chance to run. I feel, however, that adding a hard-coded sleep call isn't the cleanest solution, and that waiting for the future to complete (with a timeout, to prevent your code from getting stuck) is preferable:

```
Await.ready(something, Duration(2000, MILLISECONDS))
```

This will wait at most 2000 milliseconds for `something` to be complete, or fail otherwise.

Answer (score 1):

Your app exits before your promise is completed. At the end of your main method, just add something like `Thread.sleep(2000)` and you'll see your result.