# In android studio what should I use to have a piece of my code running the entire time

Tags: java, android

This is the code. The range is just a value that I use buttons to add or subtract to it. And once the value hits a barrier it makes the button unusable until it is off the barrier.

```
       Button button2 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button2);
    if(range == 10001) {
        button2.setEnabled(false);
    }
    else {
        button2.setEnabled(true);
    }
    Button button3 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button3);
    if(range == 1001) {
        button3.setEnabled(false);
    }
    else {
        button3.setEnabled(true);
    }
```

Comment: Down voted because the title doesn't appear to be related to the body and there is no clear question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Albeit the ambiguity of your question, I am assuming the following: you have created a dedicated process that you wish to keep running from initiation to exit of your program.
If this is the case, I would advise reading up on [Daemon threads](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2213340/what-is-daemon-thread-in-java). Hope this helps, and best of luck to you.

(Further reading on concurrency: [Oracle SE Tutorials](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/)).

Comment: Thanks i was going to delete this because after 10 mins i realized what i had to do but thanks anyway for your feedback.