# Deamon thread not working T1,T2,T3 are the classes. I wrote separately. What mistake did I make? Why is my deamon thread not reachable?

Tags: java, multithreading

My code:

```
package multithreading;

    public class JoinT1T2T3 extends Thread  
    {
        public void run()
        {
            if(Thread.currentThread().isDaemon())
            {
                System.out.println("Daemon thread is running");
            }
            else
            {
                System.out.println("Slave thread");
            }
        }


        public static void main(String args[])
        {


            Thread t=new Thread();
            t.setDaemon(true);
            T1 thread1=new T1();
            T2 thread2=new T2();
            T3 thread3=new T3();
            System.out.println("First Thread name is::: "+thread1.getName());
            thread1.setName("XXXXXXXXXX");
            System.out.println("First Thread After changing name::: "+thread1.getName());
            System.out.println("First thread's id is :::"+thread1.getId());
            thread1.start();



        try
        {

                thread1.join(3000);
            }
            catch(Exception e)
            {
                System.out.println("-----------");
            }
            //thread2.start();
            thread2.start();
            thread3.start();


        }
    }
```

Why is my daemon not reachable? Please provide me an explanation and code.

T1,T2,T3 are three different classes. The main method is also the run method. I created a new thread instance. Still getting "code not reachable". Which is if{} else{} in run method.

Comment: you have never called t.start(). the thread is never started.  Also, you have to extend thread or provide a Runnable instance to t.start()

Comment: "Why is my deamon not rachable, please provide explanation with code."  Can you explain what you mean?

Comment: Hello Peter Lawrey, I was asking why the sop in run() method is not printed to console? What shall i do test how a deamon thread works. I'd appreciate if you can provide me a good simple example illustrating how a deamon thread works OR a code which depicts the behavior of deamon thread.  Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You are getting the "not reachable" error because `JoinT1T2T3#run()` is never called anywhere.

---

## To Reach `JoinT1T2T3#run()`

In order for a `run()` method to be called, an object of its containing class should be explicitly passed to a Thread at construction-time using [`Thread#(Runnable)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#Thread-java.lang.Runnable-).  For example:

```
Thread t = new Thread(new JoinT1T2T3());
```

Now, Thread `t` will call `JoinT1T2T3#run()` whenever it starts.

---

## To Run `t`

Even if `t` is a daemon, it must still be `start()`'ed just like any other Thread, or else it will not run.  (and thus `JoinT1T2T3#run()` will never be called)  So you need to do this:

```
Thread t = new Thread(new JoinT1T2T3());
t.setDaemon(true);
t.start();
```

---

## explaining "daemon" threads

Generally speaking, in Java the only functional difference between a deamon Thread and a non-daemon Thread is that "the Java Virtual Machine exits when the only threads running are all daemon threads" ([source](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#setDaemon-boolean-)).  Other than that, a daemon Thread behaves exactly like a non-daemon Thread, syntax and all.  It must still be constructed with a `Runnable` and `start()`'ed, just like any other `Thread`.

However, because a daemon thread may be abruptly terminated when the JVM exits, daemons should be used sparingly.  In particular, daemons should not be used for any I/O or resource cleanup.  "Normal" guarantees about stuff like `finally` blocks and stack unwinding don't necessarily apply to daemon threads--if the JVM decides to exit, all daemons are immediately abandoned.  ([source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2213340/what-is-daemon-thread-in-java))

Java daemons should be used only for background housekeeping, bookkeeping, metrics, non-critical monitoring, etc.