# Why Thread is running after execution of main method?

Tags: java, multithreading

```
public class TestThread {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        System.out.println("Main Prgm Started...");
        Thread t1=new Thread(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {

                System.out.println("Thread is running..");
            }
        });

        t1.start();

        System.out.println("Main Prgm Exited...");
    }
}
```

Output is:

```
Main Prgm Started...
Main Prgm Exited...
Thread is running..
```

Comment: Because it is running in a separate thread? Unless you synchronize your threads, they run independently, in no specific order.

Answer (score 2):

Java programs will continue to run while any non-`daemon` thread is running. From the link below: "A daemon thread is a thread, that does not prevent the JVM from exiting when the program finishes but the thread is still running. An example for a daemon thread is the garbage collection. You can use the setDaemon() method to change the Thread daemon properties." [What is Daemon thread in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2213340/what-is-daemon-thread-in-java)

By default all created threads are daemon. You need to set it as non daemon.

Answer (score 1):

You are not asking your main thread to wait for `t1` to finish before exiting so there is no synchronization at all between the two threads (and you don't have any guarantees about when each of them two will execute their `println`).

If you want to make the main thread wait for the other then you should use `join()` function, eg:

```
t1.start();
t1.join();
System.out.println("Main Prgm Exited...");
```

Answer (score 0):

or use CountDownLatch:

```
import java.util.concurrent.CountDownLatch;
```

public class TestThread {

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    final CountDownLatch countDownLatch = new CountDownLatch(1);

    System.out.println("Main Prgm Started...");
    Thread t1=new Thread(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {

            System.out.println("Thread is running..");
            countDownLatch.countDown();
        }
    });

    t1.start();

    try {
        countDownLatch.await();
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    System.out.println("Main Prgm Exited...");
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

If you want to know when a program is finished you need a shutdown hook. Returning from main won't kill the program.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    System.out.println("Main Prgm Started...");
    Thread t1=new Thread(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {

            System.out.println("Thread is running..");
            try {
                Thread.sleep(1000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {}
            System.out.println("Thread is done..");
        }
    });
    t1.start();

    Runtime.getRuntime().addShutdownHook(new Thread() {
        public void run() {
            System.out.println("Main Prgm Exited...");
        }
    });
}
```