# Thread prints results after Main method finishes

Tags: java, multithreading

The final result of my calculation is 0 but when I print the result in my `run()` method, the correct result appears after my `main` method finished. Does anyone know why this keeps happening ?

```
    @Override
public void run() {

    BigDecimal counter = BigDecimal.ZERO;
    BigDecimal numOfAllThreadsBigDecimal = new BigDecimal(getNumOfAllThreads());
    BigDecimal numOfThreadBigDecimal = new BigDecimal(getNumOfThread());
    BigDecimal numerator = BigDecimal.ZERO;
    BigDecimal divisor = BigDecimal.ZERO;
    BigDecimal endResult = BigDecimal.ZERO;

    while (!isFlag()) {
        // counter % numOfAllThreads == numOfThread
        if (counter.remainder(numOfAllThreadsBigDecimal).equals(numOfThreadBigDecimal)) {
            // (4 * counter)! * (1103 + 26390 * counter)
            numerator = BigDecimalFactorial.factorial((counter.multiply(new BigDecimal(4)))).multiply(new BigDecimal(1103).add((new BigDecimal(26390).multiply(counter))));
            // (counter!)^4 * 396^4*counter
            divisor =  ((BigDecimalFactorial.factorial(counter)).pow(4)).multiply( (new BigDecimal(396).pow(4 * counter.intValue())) ) ;
            // numerator / divisor
            endResult = endResult.add(((numerator.divide(divisor, 100, RoundingMode.HALF_UP))));

            internalSteps++;

        }
        counter = counter.add(BigDecimal.ONE);
    }
    // multiply endResult by sqrt(8) / 9801
    endResult = endResult.multiply(((BigDecimalSqrt.bigSqrt(new BigDecimal(8))).divide(new BigDecimal(9801),100,RoundingMode.HALF_UP)));
    // divide 1 / pi
    endResult = BigDecimal.ONE.divide(endResult, 100, RoundingMode.HALF_UP);

    System.out.println(endResult);

    setThreadResult(endResult);
}


    public BigDecimal getValue() {

    BigDecimal result = BigDecimal.ZERO;

    for(Ramanujan worker : workers)
        result = result.add(worker.getThreadResult());
    this.value = result;

    return this.value;
}


    public static void main(String[] args) {

    CalculatePi pi = new Ramanujan();

    pi.startCalculation();
    long timeStart = System.currentTimeMillis();

    int i = 0;
    while(i < MAX_PRECISION) {
        someDelay();
        i++;
    }
    long timeStop = System.currentTimeMillis();
    pi.stopCalculation();
    System.out.println((timeStop - timeStart) + " ms");
    System.out.println("Result: " + pi.getValue());
    System.out.println("IternalSteps: " + pi.getInternalSteps());

}
```

The outcome on the Console is:

```
10004 ms (that's correct) 
Result: 0
InternalSteps: 2088
3.141592653589793...
```

The number 3.141592653589793 should come up at the result row.

Comment: Java threads can keep running after the main method ends. This answer might be helpful too: https://stackoverflow.com/a/34758651/11882002

Answer (score 1):

When you start your thread, it runs in parallel with `main` thread. If you want to stop `main` thread from execution till the other thread finishes its work, there are several approaches, but the simplest one is using `join` method. for further information read [java documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/join.html)