# Daemon and non daemon threads

Tags: java, jboss, rhq

On googling I figured out the difference between daemon and non daemon thread is that Program exits even though the daemon threads are running in background.

In which scenario we would create non daemon threads , and if program exits without waiting for the thread to complete then what is the use of creating daemon threads.Since I am not a developer I don't know these stuffs,We have option to monitor live Thread counts in JON 3.3 .So I should decide what are the metrics to be monitored.. it would be helpful if I know lot in daemon and daemon threads

If there is good article please do suggest me.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2213340/what-is-daemon-thread-in-java

Comment: If your program isn't exiting,  whether a thread is a daemon or not doesn't matter.