# How to prevent Spring app context shutdown until shutdown hook is fired

Tags: java, spring, asynchronous, spring-boot

I have a spring-boot application.

I have implemented [`SmartLifecycle`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/SmartLifecycle.html) interface in my bean which starts async snmp server in it's `start` method and stops it in it's `stop` method.

All working fine, except the fact that main application context stops right after start, so my server bean also stops right after start.

All I need is to make spring context to stop only when shutdown hook is fired.

This is not a web application, so I don't need `spring-boot-starter-web`, which is solves this problem by starting webserver which prevents context stop until webserver stops.

I can use something like `CountDownLatch` and waiting for it to be zero in my `main` method right after context starts. Somethig like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
    ConfigurableApplicationContext ctx = SpringApplication.run(SnmpTrapRetranslatorApplication.class, args);
    CountDownLatch snmpServerCloseLatch = ctx.getBean("snmpServerCloseLatch", CountDownLatch.class);
    snmpServerCloseLatch.await();
}
```

And my server bean's `start` method will create this latch with count `1`, while `stop` method will call `snmpServerCloseLatch.countDown()`.

This technique is described [here](https://spring.io/guides/gs/reactor-thumbnailer/).

But what wrong with this is that my `main` method is responsible for waiting my custom server bean to stop. I feel this just not right.

How for example `spring-boot-starter-web` do this? When it starts tomcat, it keeps running until shutdown hook is received and it don't need to have any managing code in the `main` method. It stops only when context receiving shoutdown signal.

The same behaviour is for example when I have `@Scheduled` method in my bean. Spring also doesn't stops context automatically. Only on `CTRL-C`.

I want to achieve similar effect. My `main` method should have only one line: start the context. Context should start and stop my async server when it starts or stops (already achieved by `SmartLifecycle`) and should not stop until shutdown is requested (CTRL-C, SIGINT etc).

Answer (score 7):

```
    SpringApplication app = new SpringApplication(Main.class);
    app.setRegisterShutdownHook(false);
    ConfigurableApplicationContext applicationContext= app.run();
    Runtime.getRuntime().addShutdownHook(new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            //do your things
            applicationContext.close();
        }
    }));
```

Comment: This way is more perfect，Cancel spring's self-registered hook, and call spring's context.close() directly after the business logic has finished processing its own registered hooks.

Comment: @lyrl Except this is not a solution to the problem mentioned. :) The problem was with the fact that Spring context was closed right after start and the reason was: the absence of alive non-daemon thread. This "solution" doesn't prevent this at all. All it does is allows custom logic to be executed on shutdown, which has nothing to do with the question asked.

Comment: @RuslanStelmachenko I have tried to cancel the spring self-registered shutdownhok, only when the custom logic execution applicationContext.close after the other components will receive the signal to close

Comment: @lyrl I understand. And maybe this solution answers **your** question. But this has nothing to do with the original question. It's like if I would ask "What time is now?" and someone answers me: "Green". :) So this couldn't be considered as a correct answer to the question asked. Anyway, for your problem there is more elegant solution too: `app`[`.getShutdownHandlers()`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/SpringApplication.html#getShutdownHandlers--)`.add(() -> { /* your handler body */});`.

Answer (score 6):

My investigation lead me to the core of the problem: [daemon threads](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2213340/what-is-daemon-thread-in-java).

The snmp server implementation which I use (snmp4j) use daemon threads internally. So even when snmp server started, there are no more live user threads in JVM, so it exits.

**TL/DR:**

Just add this method to any bean (snmp server bean is good candidate for this):

```
@Scheduled(fixedDelay = 1000 * 60 * 60) // every hour
public void doNothing() {
    // Forces Spring Scheduling managing thread to start
}
```

(Do not forget to add `@EnableScheduling` to your spring configuration).

**Explanation:**

To prevent stopping spring context, while SNMP server is still running, we need **any** non-daemon thread to be alive in JVM. Not necessarily `main` thread. So we can let `main` method to finish.

1. We can run new non-daemon thread from our server bean's `start` method. This thread will `wait` on some lock in `while` loop checking for some `running` variable, while our `stop` method will set this `running` variable to `false` and `notifyAll` on this lock.

   This way, our non-daemon thread will be alive until shotdown hook is triggered (and prevents JVM to exit).
   After shutdown hook, spring context lifecycle `close` method will call all `SmartLifecycle` bean's `close` methods, that will lead to SNMP server bean's `stop` method call, that will lead to set `running` to false, that will lead to our non-daemon thread to stop, that allow JVM to stop gracefully.
2. Or instead we can use Spring's scheduling thread in similar way. It also is non-daemon thread, so it will prevent JVM to exit. And Spring manages this thread itself, so it will automatically stop it when shutdown hook is triggered.

   To make Spring's scheduling thread to start we need any `@Scheduled` method in any bean.

---

I think that first (manual) approach is still more "correct", while requires more async coding (which is error-prone as we all know). Who knows how Spring will change it's scheduling implementation in the future.