# Configure Spring to run without web services

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I want to create Spring Boot project which runs without web services because I need to use it to process Kafka messages, SQL queries and webflux client.

Is it possible to disable the rest API functionality and to disable tomcat from exposing server on the network?

Comment: please have a look at  https://stackoverflow.com/a/50825789/8112217

Comment: I added `spring.main.web-application-type=NONE` but right after the application starts it exits. I imaged that it will run like a daemon without listing on  port but it's not true.

Comment: the following answer might help https://stackoverflow.com/a/37766059/8112217