# actionListener interfaces actionPerformed method not working with Timer class

Tags: java, date, actionlistener

the following program is suppose to print the date after every second. however this is not working for an known reason.

i have implemented the ActionListener interface in the following class and the actionPerformed method:

```
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.util.Date;

public class CurrentTimePrinter implements ActionListener{

        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
        System.out.println(new Date());

    }
}
```

this is the tester class:

```
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.Timer;


public class CurrentTimePrinterTester {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ActionListener listener = new CurrentTimePrinter();

        Timer t = new Timer(1000, listener);
        t.start();
    }
}
```

Comment: You need to create a Swing GUI or other reason for the Swing event dispatch thread to continue running.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to execute your code on a [non-daemon thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2213340/what-is-daemon-thread-in-java). What currently happens is that the `Timer` starts as a daemon thread, but as `main` returns the the JVM exits.

You can start the timer from the EDT (which is non-daemon) like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    ActionListener listener = new CurrentTimePrinter();
    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> new Timer(1000, listener).start());
}
```

and this keeps the JVM alive.

A few extra notes on threading:

The [`swing.Timer`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/Timer.html) is a simplified class that was customized for use with GUIs. With this comes the disadvantage of less flexibility. The thread on which all such timers run is set in the background and is daemon.

The [`util.Timer`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Timer.html) has by default a non-daemon thread and has the flexibility to be [created otherwise](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Timer.html#Timer-boolean-). Each timer has its own thread.