# Java Thread for background services in Java EE application (set daemon and priority)?

Tags: java, multithreading, jakarta-ee, web

I'm running a service of generating a big file (It is a report in BIRT) in Java back code and it takes a lot of time my question is what is the best way to manage it with

daemon = true or
daemon = false

and the priority

```
new Thread(new Runnable() {
                public void run(){
                    try { 
                     task.run();
                     engine.destroy( );
                    }
                     catch ( EngineException e1 ) {
                         System.err.println( "Report " + reportFilepath + " run failed.\n" );
                         System.err.println( e1.toString( ) );
                     }
                }
        }).start();
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is Daemon thread in Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2213340/what-is-daemon-thread-in-java)

Comment: I know the difference but I dont se what is the best choice in a Java EE app and what priority use

Comment: There is no 'best choice', it depends on your requirements.

Comment: thanks dude for your info

Answer (score 2):

Creating `new Thread()`s in Java EE is considered bad practice.  Instead, you should use a service such as `ManagedExecutorService` (MES) and submit runnables to it.

The benefit of using a MES over running your own threads is that the resources used by a MES can be controlled by the Java EE app server.

Now to answer your question about daemon threads and priorities.

**daemons:** Submitting tasks to an MES is always non-blocking, and the result of a task can optionally be checked, so this essentially makes these tasks daemon threads.

**priority:** there isn't a Java EE standard way that I know of to control thread priority.  You will have to check with your application server implementation to see if there are properties you can pass in during task submit to indicate a thread priority.

Answer (score 0):

There is only one difference between a daemon thread and a normal thread: The existence of a normal, running thread will prevent the JVM from shutting itself down, but the existence of a running daemon thread will not. There is no impact on performance

Comment: and what priority of use will you recommend me in a java ee app?

Comment: By default I would leave it as normal. Unless there is an actual reason to change it. The following article does a decent job at explaining the impact of changing priority on Windows or Linux without going to in depth. http://www.javamex.com/tutorials/threads/priority_what.shtml