# Why doesn't my thread wait for CompletableFutures to complete with `allOf()`?

Tags: java, multithreading, java-8, completable-future

I'm studying `CompletableFuture` in Java 1.8 and having trouble trying to understand `allOf`. It seems the main thread doesn't wait for any `CompletableFuture` to complete.

See https://github.com/nurkiewicz/reactive/blob/master/src/test/java/be/more/reactive/S03_AllOf.java for the example I'm testing.

The test job finishes before any result is printed.

There are two (ugly?) ways to circumvent this: 1) set a timeout on the main thread and wait for both to finish. 2) set a `.get()` at the end and it will become a blocking task.

Why is this?

Code fragment:

```
package be.more.reactive;

import be.more.reactive.util.BaseTest;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;

import java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture;

public class S03_AllOf extends BaseTest {

    private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(S03_AllOf.class);

    private final CompletableFuture<String> futureResult1 = getFutureQueryResult("1"); //.exceptionally() ??
    private final CompletableFuture<String> futureResult2 = getFutureQueryResult("2");
    private final CompletableFuture<String> futureResult3 = getFutureQueryResult("3");
    private final CompletableFuture<String> futureResult4 = getFutureQueryResult("4");

    @Test
    public void allOf() throws Exception {
        final CompletableFuture<Void> futureResult = CompletableFuture.allOf(   //Void ?? I want List<String>
                futureResult1, futureResult2, futureResult3, futureResult4
        );

//        futureResult.thenAccept((Void vd) -> vd.??)   //no, it won't work

        futureResult.thenRun(() -> {
            try {
                log.debug("Query result 1: '{}'", futureResult1.get());
                log.debug("Query result 2: '{}'", futureResult2.get());
                log.debug("Query result 3: '{}'", futureResult3.get());
                log.debug("Query result 4: '{}'", futureResult4.get());   //a lot of manual work

                log.debug("Now do on complete");    //handling onComplete
            } catch (Exception e) {
                log.error("", e);
            }
        });

    }

}
```

And in BaseTest:

```
protected CompletableFuture<String> getFutureQueryResult(final String queryId) {
    return CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(
            () -> db.apply(new Query(queryId))

    );
}
```

And in DB.java

```
package be.more.reactive.db;

import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

import static org.apache.commons.lang3.RandomStringUtils.randomAlphabetic;
import static org.apache.commons.lang3.RandomUtils.nextInt;
import static org.apache.commons.lang3.RandomUtils.nextLong;

public class DB {
    public String apply(Query query) {
        try {
            TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(nextLong(2, 4));
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return String.format("%s_%s", randomAlphabetic(nextInt(4, 12)), query.getId());
    }
}
```

Comment: There is no `main` in your linked example. And on StackOverflow, you should include the code **in the question itself**. Anyway, assuming you mean the test method, have you read the documentation of `thenRun`?

Comment: @RealSkeptic: I'm talking about the thread called 'main'.

Comment: Fine, but still, you are not waiting for anything, so what do you expect the calling thread to do? It just terminates.

Comment: @RealSkeptic: Well, this repo isn't mine, but written by nurkiewicz, who I thought to be a very well tutor on a youtube video about CompletableFutures etc. That's why I'm a little bit confused about it. I'll ask him.

Comment: @RealSkeptic I suggested a pull request to the author of the gitrepo and I added the code to this post.

Answer (score 4):

From the Javadoc

> Returns a new CompletableFuture that is completed when all of the given CompletableFutures complete.

A `Future` is an async task which doesn't block until you invoke `get` (only blocks if the task is still running).

In this case, the `CompleteableFuture` is a compound `Future` of all the `CompletableFuture`s. This future is still going to be a blocking async call and you must invoke `get` or `join` to wait for all futures to complete. Again, from the javadoc

> CompletableFutures before continuing a program, as in: `CompletableFuture.allOf(c1, c2, c3).join();`.

Your (2) solution, in my opinion, is neither ugly nor unexpected functionality.

Comment: So, do you agree with me then that the unit-test in the provided link does not really use the feature of `allOf`?

Answer (score 2):

The behavior you are seeing is not unexpected. When you create a `CompletableFuture`, you are basically scheduling a piece of work that would run asynchronously.

#### Things to understand about `CompletableFuture` before using `allOf`

Let's say we create a `CompletableFuture` like so

```java
var myFuture = CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> myLongRunningOperation());
```

- A `CompletableFuture` would call `myLongRunningOperation` on a separate thread.
- `CompletableFuture` runs the tasks using an `ExecutorService`, that can be provided during the creation of the `CompletableFuture`.
- If no `ExecutorService` is provided, it uses the one provided by [ForkJoinPool#commonPool](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ForkJoinPool.html#commonPool--), which provides a thread pool of [Daemon Threads](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2213348/2498327).
- The task `() -> myLongRunningOperation()` would be submitted to the `ExecutorService` irrespective of whether someone is waiting for the result of `myFuture`, i.e. irrespective of whether `myFuture.join()` or `myFuture.get()` are called.

In your test method, this is what is happening behind the scenes

```java
@Test
public void allOf() throws Exception {
    // Schedules a computation (futureResult) on a different thread whose only 
    // work is to wait for the futures futureResult1, futureResult2, futureResult3 
    // and futureResult4 to complete
    final CompletableFuture<Void> futureResult = CompletableFuture.allOf(
            futureResult1, futureResult2, futureResult3, futureResult4
    );

    //  Schedules a computation that prints the results AFTER the futureResult is complete.
    futureResult.thenRun(() -> {
        try {
            log.debug("Query result 1: '{}'", futureResult1.get());
            log.debug("Query result 2: '{}'", futureResult2.get());
            log.debug("Query result 3: '{}'", futureResult3.get());
            log.debug("Query result 4: '{}'", futureResult4.get());
            log.debug("Now do on complete");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            log.error("", e);
        }
    });

    // Nothing more to do, so exit

}
```

but, when you call `.join()` or `.get()` the thread executing the Test (main thread) will wait for it the scheduled computation to complete before the it exits.

So, if you want your test to wait for the scheduled computation to complete before it exists,

```java
//  Schedules a computation that prints the results ONCE the futureResult is complete.
final CompletableFuture<Void> myFuture = futureResult.thenRun(() -> {
    try {
        log.debug("Query result 1: '{}'", futureResult1.get());
        log.debug("Query result 2: '{}'", futureResult2.get());
        log.debug("Query result 3: '{}'", futureResult3.get());
        log.debug("Query result 4: '{}'", futureResult4.get());   //a lot of manual work

        log.debug("Now do on complete");    //handling onComplete
    } catch (Exception e) {
        log.error("", e);
    }
});

// Wait for the myFuture to complete (sucessfully or throw an exception) before continuing.
myFuture.get();
```

Setting a timeout on the main thread to wait for the Future to complete is an anti-pattern.

- If you care about the result and need to wait for the future to
  complete, call `join()` or `get()` based on how you want to do
  exception handling.
- If you do not care about the result, but would like the application
  to wait for the future to complete, then create a custom executor
  service that creates `non-daemon` threads.