# Scala Process never end when applying Future and ThreadPools for Multi-threading

Tags: java, multithreading, scala

Here's the code snippet:

```
object Test {
  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    // MARK: parallelization
    val pool = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(3)
    implicit val xc = ExecutionContext.fromExecutorService(pool)
    var taskQueue = new ArrayBuffer[Future[Unit]]()

    for (i <- 0 until 10)  {
      try {
        taskQueue += Future {
          print(s"in_${i}\n")
          Thread.sleep(1000)
        }
      } catch {
        case t: Throwable =>  {
          print(t)
        }
      }
    }

    val importTasks = Future.sequence(taskQueue)
    importTasks.onSuccess { case res => print("finishOnSuccess") }
    Await.result(importTasks, Duration.Inf)
  }
}
```

it will hang forever after all jobs are executed with the following output:

in_1
  in_2
  in_0
  in_4
  in_3
  in_5
  in_8
  in_6
  in_7
  in_9
  finishOnSuccess

I tried to call `System.exit(0)` at the end of `main` method but still no use. Any suggestions? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to `shutdown` `ExecutorService` of `pool` by `pool.shutdown()` after `Await`. Since the `newFixedThreadPool` is creating **non-daemon thread** by [defaultThreadFactory](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Executors.html#defaultThreadFactory--).

and this Post explain more about **Daemon** thread and **Non-Daemon** thread:

[What is Daemon thread in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2213340/what-is-daemon-thread-in-java)