# How to release a port from the state LISTEN at the server side

Tags: java, sockets, exception, server, serversocket

I am new to sockets in JAVA. Recently, I am trying to build a server-client program that clients can search a word from the dictionary in server side and the server will return the defintion of the word to the clients. The code in server side is as the following:

```
public class DictionaryServer {

private static int port;
private static String dicFile;
static Map<String, String> dictionary = new HashMap<String, String>();
int userCounter = 0;

public static void main(String[] args) {

    //check if starting the server in valid format
    if (args.length != 2) {
        System.err.println("Invalid format to start DictionaryServer"); 
        System.err.println("Usage: java DictionaryServer <port number> <the name of dictionary>");
        System.exit(1);
    }


    port = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
    dicFile = args[1];


    try{
        System.out.println("IP: " + InetAddress.getLocalHost());
        System.out.println("port: " + port);
    }
    catch(UnknownHostException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    DictionaryServer s = new DictionaryServer();
    s.server(port, dicFile);

}


public void server(int port, String dicFile) {
    ServerSocketFactory serverSocket = ServerSocketFactory.getDefault();

    try(ServerSocket server = serverSocket.createServerSocket(port)){

        System.out.println("Server IP: " + server.getInetAddress());
        System.out.println("Listening for client connections...");

        while(true){
            Socket client = server.accept();
            System.out.println("Client \"" + client.getRemoteSocketAddress().toString()
                    + "\""+ " is connecting.");


            Thread t = new Thread(() -> service(client, dicFile));
            t.start();

        }
    }
    catch (UnknownHostException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    catch(IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}

public void service(Socket client, String dicFile){
    try(Socket clientSocket = client){
        // Input and Output stream of the client
        DataInputStream input = new DataInputStream(
                clientSocket.getInputStream());
        DataOutputStream output = new DataOutputStream(
                clientSocket.getOutputStream());

        //check request
        int action = input.readInt();   //1:add, 2:remove, 3:query
        String word = input.readUTF();

        //choose action
        Dic d = new Dic(dicFile);
        switch(action){
            case 1: //add
                String definition = input.readUTF();
                output.writeUTF(d.add(word, definition, dicFile));
                break;

            case 2: //remove
                output.writeUTF(d.remove(word, dicFile));
                break;

            case 3: //query
                output.writeUTF(d.query(word, dicFile));
                break;
        }
    }
    catch(IOException e){
        String message=e.getMessage();
        System.out.println(message);
        System.out.println();
    }   
}
```

I am got stucked in an error when I try to restart the serverprogram: java.net.BindException: Address already in use (Bind failed)

For example, last time I execute the server program with the port 4000 and it worked, but if I want to execute the server program with the same port again, the exception will show up. I checked what the port 4000 is doing by "lsof -i:4000" in terminal which told me:

```
COMMAND   PID USER   FD   TYPE             DEVICE SIZE/OFF NODE NAME
java    19683 Andy    7u  IPv6 0x43e8f876eb74b731      0t0  TCP *:terabase (LISTEN)
```

Does anyone know how I can fix this problem? Thank you!

Comment: Once the application terminates, the port is eventually released by the OS. It just takes some time.

Comment: You must kill the previous running servers  or make your port be configurable at runtime to be different

Comment: Thanks for reply. But I have waited for a long while but they are still in LISTEN. Is it possible that I can terminate them when I exit the server program by add some codes? For no the only way works is to close my Eclipse.

Comment: Killing the main thread does not kill the whole JVM when other non daemon threads are still running. Try `Thread.setDaemon(true)`. For more info see https://stackoverflow.com/a/2213348/2920861

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need make sure your program has really exited, and you also need to set `reuseAddress`. To do that you have to create the server socket without binding, set the option, and then bind it, in three different steps:

```
ServerSocket server = serverSocketFactory.createServerSocket();
server.setReuseAddress(true);
server.bind(new InetSocketAddress(port));
```