# spring boot maven plugin stop goal

Tags: spring, maven, spring-boot

Spring boot maven plugin stop goal fails to stop the application and leaves the application process hanging (and I and cannot start another process using the same port).
This is the plugin configuration I have:

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.5.6.RELEASE</version>
            <configuration>
                <jvmArguments>-DCONFIG_ENVIRONMENT=functionaltest</jvmArguments>
                <mainClass>...</mainClass>
                <fork>true</fork>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>start-service</id>
                    <phase>pre-integration-test</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>start</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
                <execution>
                    <id>stop-service</id>
                    <phase>post-integration-test</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>stop</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```

I can't find any reference to a bug causing this behaviour. Am I using the plugin in a way it was not meant to be used maybe?

Comment: Why are you using `<fork>true</fork>`? If you want the spring-boot application to be run in a forked JVM then I think you can add `<fork>true</true>` to the `<configuration>` block but it looks wrong sitting inside the `<execution>` blocks.

Comment: @glitch yes, I tried that as well. I have updated the code in the question to be like that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the problem: the spring boot application (in its main thread) starts a new thread that prevents the jvm from shutting down. Changing the "child" thread to be a daemon thread solved the issue.

**Code with issue**

```
        private ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor(r -> {
            Thread t = new Thread(r);
            return t;
        });
```

**Code that solved the issue**

```
        private ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor(r -> {
            Thread t = new Thread(r);
            t.setDaemon(true);
            return t;
        });
```

Check out [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2213340/what-is-daemon-thread-in-java) for more details about daemon thrreads in Java.

Answer (score 1):

change config to this and if you want use remote debug uncomment 
for start app in maven run  :    **spring-boot:stop clean spring-boot:start**

```
<plugin>
                        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                        <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                        <configuration>
                             <executable>true</executable>
                            <fork>true</fork>
                            <addResources>true</addResources>
                            <!-- <jvmArguments> -->
                            <!-- -agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,address=localhost:5005,server=y,suspend=n -->
                            <!-- </jvmArguments> -->
                        </configuration>

                    </plugin>
```