# Why don't Akka Streams application terminate normally?

Tags: scala, akka-stream, alpakka

I wrote this simple application using Alpakka Cassandra Library

```
package com.abhi

import akka.actor.ActorSystem
import akka.stream.{ActorMaterializer, ClosedShape}
import akka.stream.alpakka.cassandra.scaladsl.CassandraSource
import akka.stream.scaladsl.{Flow, GraphDSL, RunnableGraph, Sink}
import com.datastax.driver.core.{Cluster, Row, SimpleStatement}
import scala.concurrent.Await
import scala.concurrent.duration._

object MyApp extends App {
   implicit val actorSystem = ActorSystem()
   implicit val actorMaterializer = ActorMaterializer()
   implicit val session = Cluster
      .builder
      .addContactPoints(List("localhost") :_*)
      .withPort(9042)
      .withCredentials("foo", "bar")
      .build
      .connect("foobar")
   val stmt = new SimpleStatement("SELECT col1, col2 FROM foo").setFetchSize(20)
   val source = CassandraSource(stmt)
   val toFoo = Flow[Row].map(row => Foo(row.getLong(0), row.Long(1)))
   val sink = Sink.foreach[Foo](foo => println(foo.col1, foo.col2))
   val graph = RunnableGraph.fromGraph(GraphDSL.create(sink){ implicit b =>
      s =>
      import GraphDSL.Implicits._
      source.take(10) ~> toFoo ~> s
      ClosedShape
   })
   // let us run the graph
   val future = graph.run()
   import actorSystem.dispatcher
   future.onComplete{_ =>
      session.close()
      Await.result(actorSystem.terminate(), Duration.Inf)
   }
   Await.result(future, Duration.Inf)
   System.exit(0)
}

case class Foo(col1: Long, col2: Long)
```

This application runs exactly as expected it prints 10 rows on the screen.

But post that it hangs. When the `System.exit(0)` call is executed it throws an exception

```
Exception: sbt.TrapExitSecurityException thrown from the UncaughtExceptionHandler in thread "run-main-0"
```

But still the application does not stop running. it just hangs.

I don't understand why doesn't this application terminate normally (in fact it shouldn't even need system.exit(0) call.

The only way to exit this application is via a control C.

Comment: Hi, I am exactly facing similar issue. Could you please tell me how you fixed it ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This might happen because sbt runs your code in its own JVM instance, your `System.exit` will then exit sbt's JVM giving the above result.

Did you try setting: `fork in run := true` somewhere in your sbt build?

I'm also not sure it is a good idea to use `actorSystem.dispatcher` to execute your `onComplete` callback (because you use it to wait for the termination of the actor system itself).

Something you could try instead:

```
import actorSystem.dispatcher
future.onComplete{ _ =>
  session.close()
  actorSystem.terminate()
}
Await.result(actorSystem.whenTerminated, Duration.Inf)
```

Note that the JVM will exit without you needing to call `System.exit` when the only threads left are daemon threads (see for example [What is Daemon thread in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2213340/what-is-daemon-thread-in-java#2213348)).

Comment: I did it similar fashion, But does not work , `fork in run := true` in build.sbt and then I did the code change like this. However my code does not terminate at all. Thanks in advance