# What can possibly go wrong when halting the JVM while a thread is doing I/O?

Tags: java, multithreading, io, jvm

I read in [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2213340/what-is-a-daemon-thread-in-java#comment36972450_2213443)

> don’t call System.exit(…) if you think there might be running threads
>   doing I/O

Is killing a not-finished I/O operation potentially much worse than killing a, for example, DB transaction?

Comment: ... what could possibly NOT go wrong to a(ny) running Java Threads when you terminate the JVM??

Comment: @Stultuske There are threads that finish cleanly when the JVM ends: daemon threads like the garbage collector.

Comment: we're not talking about those, but about an I/O execution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> What can possibly go wrong when halting the JVM while a thread is doing I/O?

Because if you do, it is difficult to know for sure if the I/O operation completed before the JVM exited.  For a read operation that is probably OK, but an incomplete write could result in permanent loss of data.

> Is killing a not-finished I/O operation potentially much worse than killing a, for example, DB transaction?

Yes, it is worse.

If you kill a JVM while a database transaction<sup>1</sup> is in progress, the database will revert to a consistent state.  This *should* happen even if the JVM is killed without the normal JVM shutdown hooks getting to run.  This is implemented by the database writing data to the file system in a controlled way that is resilient to being interrupted; i.e. some combination of atomic writes, and writing things in a specific order.  The database may need to do some recovery on restart, but committed data will have been safely saved.  (That is the D (durability) in ACID.)

---

<sup>1 - assuming that the database has ACID properties, and you don't suffer catastrophic media failure.</sup>

Answer (score 0):

System.exit() kills the whole JVM on the box (initiates the JVM shutdown sequence). So invoking this will kill your web app/service, but probably also your app server. If you were deploying anything else on said server, those go down as well. Same goes for I/O operations.