# How to check if a thread is a daemon thread in the IntelliJ IDEA debugger?

Tags: java, debugging, intellij-idea, jvm

I am troubleshooting a JOGL application shutdown. As the application is not terminating properly, I would like to know which of the threads is causing this. Is there a way to check in the debugger which threads are [non-daemon](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2213340/what-is-a-daemon-thread-in-java) ones?

[image]

If there is nothing in the IDE for this, is there some other way to check for this, perhaps some clever expression I could enter as a watch expression to list the non-deamon threads?

Comment: Note: an issue exists to add the support into the debugger: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-132042

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you can put break point you can use call `Evaluate expression (Alt + F8)` and type `Thread.getThreads()` the you can inspect every thread if it's deamon.

Comment: Or you can evaluate `Thread.currentThread().isDeamon()` when you breakpoint a specific thread.

Answer (score 1):

Right click on a stack frame and click "Export Treads...".
It will create a text description of every thread and their stack and stuff but most importantly the daemon threads will say "daemon" next to them.

```
"RMI Scheduler(0)@4275" daemon prio=5 tid=0x14 nid=NA waiting
  java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING
      at jdk.internal.misc.Unsafe.park(Unsafe.java:-1)
      at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.parkNanos(LockSupport.java:234)
...
```