# RxJava Schedulers.io doesn't work in maven project

Tags: java, rx-java, rx-java2

I have created a maven project in Intellij IDEA , I'm trying to execute the below simple rxjava code

```
Observable.just(1,2,3,4)
          .observeOn(Schedulers.io())
          .subscribe(new Consumer<Integer>() {
              @Override
              public void accept(Integer integer) throws Exception {
                  System.out.println(integer);
              }
         });
```

I expect the result `1 , 2 , 3 , 4` to be printed in the `io` thread. But when I run the code, it doesn't print anything.
If I remove the `observeOn(Schedulers.io)` , then it prints as expected in the main thread. 
I created creating a custom Thread pool as shown below

```
Executor executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(1);
Observable.just(1,2,3,4)
    .observeOn(Schedulers.from(executor))
    .subscribe(new Consumer<Integer>() {
        @Override
        public void accept(Integer integer) throws Exception {
            System.out.println(integer);
        }
    });
```

This is working properly. The `Schedulers.newThread()` and `Schedulers.computation()` threads also working properly. 
Only `Schedulers.io` has no effect in the code. Why is that?

Below is my dependency for Rxjava

```
  <dependency>
        <groupId>io.reactivex.rxjava2</groupId>
        <artifactId>rxjava</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.4</version>
    </dependency>
```

Comment: Add `Thread.sleep(1000)` at the end of your main method

Comment: Why is that exactly?

Comment: your main method completes before you see the results of your computation. `Thread.sleep()` will add a delay so you can see the results

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The RxJava `Schedulers.io()` schedulers use deamon threads.

> A daemon thread is a thread that does not prevent the JVM from exiting
>   when the program finishes but the thread is still running. An example
>   for a daemon thread is the garbage collection.

[source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2213340/what-is-a-daemon-thread-in-java)

In your first example, the main method finishes, and the program terminates so you don't see any output. Adding `Thread.sleep()` at the end of your main method will delay the exit and you should be able to see the output.

I assume `Executors.newFixedThreadPool(1)` doesn't use deamon threads, so it blocks the main method from exiting and you see different output.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the explanation. I have one more query. As you mentioned _**A daemon thread does not prevent the JVM from exiting when the program finishes but the thread is still running**_. So, the `Schedulers.io()` is still active even if the main thread has terminated. Then why doesn't it print the `System.out.println(integer);`  in the `subscriber`? Is it because the `Consumer` anonymous class instance would be cleaned up by the GC? Wouldn't the `Consumer` class instance  be holding by the `io` thread? Please correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: Okay, I got the answer. It seems _**If JVM finds running daemon thread, it terminates the thread and after that shutdown itself. JVM does not care whether Daemon thread is running or not.**_