# in Java (thread.setDaemon(true) means interrupt thread when main thread interrupted) is true?

Tags: java, multithreading, daemon

my statement (thread.setDaemon(true) means interrupt thread when main thread interrupted) is true?

setDaemon(true) whats mean?

Comment: Out of interest - where did you get this information from?

Comment: No, it means exactly what it says in the Javadoc. No more and no less.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a daemon thread in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2213340/what-is-a-daemon-thread-in-java)

Answer (score 6):

No, it's not about *interrupting*. It's purely about whether the thread should prevent the JVM exiting.

The JVM will terminate when there are no "non-daemon" threads left alive. If you create a bunch of threads and then let the main thread finish, and you want the program to stay running due to those threads, they should *not* be daemon threads. If you want the new threads to be purely background threads, and you're happy for the program to finish when the main thread finishes, then they *should* be daemon threads.