# Interrupting read method with future and completableFuture

Tags: java, future, completable-future

While solving the task, I've noticed a behavior I can not explain.

My task was to read from InputStream and interrupt that reading after a timeout. Even though lots of people say blocking read can not be interrupted, I've achieved that goal using `CompletableFuture`

```
public void startReader() {
   CompletableFuture<Void> future = CompletableFuture.runAsync(() -> doRead(System.in));
   future.get(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
}

private void doRead(InputStream in) {
   try {
      new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in)).readLine();
   } catch (IOException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
   }
}
```

But when I implement the same using `Future`, I can see `TimeoutException` been thrown into JVM, but I still can see that **reading thread was not terminated and still running**.

```
public void startReader() throws ExecutionException, InterruptedException, TimeoutException {
   Future<?> future = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor().submit(() -> doRead(System.in));
   future.get(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
}

private void doRead(InputStream in) {
   try {
      new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in)).readLine();
   } catch (IOException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
   }
}
```

Why there is such a difference? I believe `CompletableFuture` does not make any magic

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Neither of your code snippets will stop the "reading" thread when you reached the `future.get(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS);`. They will continue waiting for your input from `System.in`. If you want to stop it you should send an interrupt to that thread and hope the thread react on it. Or you can force kill the thread, obviously.

However, the `CompletableFuture.runAsync()` and `Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor()` calls use different threads, specially using different [daemon](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html) flags (see [What is a daemon thread in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2213340/what-is-a-daemon-thread-in-java)). When you place a `System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().isDaemon());` inside your `doRead()` method you will see that `CompletableFuture.runAsync` uses a daemon thread (so it doesn't block the JVM from terminating) where `Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor()` does not (and keeps the JVM alive).