# broker start up,where the code show the block?

Tags: java, rocketmq

broker start up is not exit,where the code shows the block?
i find some shedule,but not find anywhere await.
in this code,i just fond some server,but execute over this,why main thread not exit?
i enter server to find some detail,and just find some shedules,not find anywhere do wait() to blocking the main therad?

```
public void start() throws Exception {
        if (this.messageStore != null) {
            this.messageStore.start();
        }

        if (this.remotingServer != null) {
            this.remotingServer.start();
        }

        if (this.fastRemotingServer != null) {
            this.fastRemotingServer.start();
        }

        if (this.fileWatchService != null) {
            this.fileWatchService.start();
        }

        if (this.brokerOuterAPI != null) {
            this.brokerOuterAPI.start();
        }

        if (this.pullRequestHoldService != null) {
            this.pullRequestHoldService.start();
        }

        if (this.clientHousekeepingService != null) {
            this.clientHousekeepingService.start();
        }

        if (this.filterServerManager != null) {
            this.filterServerManager.start();
        }

        if (!messageStoreConfig.isEnableDLegerCommitLog()) {
            startProcessorByHa(messageStoreConfig.getBrokerRole());
            handleSlaveSynchronize(messageStoreConfig.getBrokerRole());
            this.registerBrokerAll(true, false, true);
        }

        this.scheduledExecutorService.scheduleAtFixedRate(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    BrokerController.this.registerBrokerAll(true, false, brokerConfig.isForceRegister());
                } catch (Throwable e) {
                    log.error("registerBrokerAll Exception", e);
                }
            }
        }, 1000 * 10, Math.max(10000, Math.min(brokerConfig.getRegisterNameServerPeriod(), 60000)), TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);

        if (this.brokerStatsManager != null) {
            this.brokerStatsManager.start();
        }

        if (this.brokerFastFailure != null) {
            this.brokerFastFailure.start();
        }


    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you need [What is a daemon thread in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2213340/what-is-a-daemon-thread-in-java).

Because each scheduler has some thread are running, and they are NON-DAEMON threads, so before these threads are finished, the jvm will not exit.