# Daemon And Non-Daemon Threads In Java

Tags: multithreading, jvm, virtual-machine, daemon

JVM in Java is responsible to create a Non-Daemon Thread when executing a Java program. Is it correct?
If so, who is responsible to create Daemon Threads in Java?
Programmers and JVM both create Non-Daemon Threads? Is it correct?
Looking for a clear explanation.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is a daemon thread in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2213340/what-is-a-daemon-thread-in-java)

Comment: Yes. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 3):

It doesn’t matter whether “the JVM” or “the programmer” started a thread. A thread is a daemon thread when [`setDaemon(true)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/15/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Thread.html#setDaemon(boolean)) has been called on it before starting or a daemon thread created the thread without calling [`setDaemon`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/15/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Thread.html#setDaemon(boolean)). That’s it.

The [documentation of `Thread`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/15/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Thread.html) also says:

> When a Java Virtual Machine starts up, there is usually a single non-daemon thread (which typically calls the method named `main` of some designated class).

There is no responsibility to create daemon threads. Marking a thread as daemon has only one implication which the documentation continues to explain:

> The Java Virtual Machine continues to execute threads until either of the following occurs:
>
> - The `exit` method of class `Runtime` has been called and the security manager has permitted the exit operation to take place.
> - All threads that are not daemon threads have died, either by returning from the call to the `run` method or by throwing an exception that propagates beyond the `run` method.

So, that’s the only implication; the existence of a non-daemon thread may prevent the JVM from terminating automatically, whereas threads marked as daemon do not.