# How to prevent a Timer from running in the background?

Tags: java, javafx, timer

I'm using JavaFX 8 to develop a little game as a side project and I want to use the `Timer` class from the `Java.util` package.

The thing is, whenever I schedule the `Timer` to do something, I don't know how to stop it, and it keeps running in the background even when I've already closed the window.

I eventually made a method called `handleShutDown()` that's called whenever the `Stage` is set on hidden, using the code below.

```
stage.setOnHidden(windowEvent -> controller.handleShutDown());
```

I also tried a couple of different ways to cancel the `Timer` in the `handleShutDown()` method. I tried calling the Timer's `cancel()` method, the Timer's `purge()` method, setting the Timer to `null`, and even replacing the Timer with a new one (`timer = new Timer()`).

```
public void handleShutDown() {
//    timer.cancel();
//    timer.purge();
//    timer = new Timer();
    timer = null;
    Platform.exit();
}
```

I'm not sure what to try next...

Here's how I know the application is still running, since the red box is still there even after I closed the window, which should not happen. And everything was fine until I started using timers. Or maybe I shouldn't use a Timer?

[image: Here's how I know the application is still running]

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your application keeps running because a user thread is still alive. See [What is a Daemon Thread in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2213340/what-is-a-daemon-thread-in-java). This is how you start a Timer with a daemon thread: `Timer timer = new Timer(true);`

Comment: _ I want to use the Timer class from the Java.util package._ Why? Learn to use fx concurrency support

Comment: In case you haven't considered animations, make sure [you're using the right tool for the job](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9966136/javafx-periodic-background-task/60685975#60685975).

Comment: Also, could you provide a [mre], please? Calling [Timer#cancel()](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/16/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Timer.html#cancel()) should be working for you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To make a `Thread` run in the background and die when the main thread dies, use the `daemon` boolean property (See: [Daemon Threads](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2213340/what-is-a-daemon-thread-in-java)):

```java
Thread thread = new Thread();
thread.setDaemon(true); // this thread will die when the main thread dies
```

`Timer` uses `TimerThread` which extends Java's `Thread`. When constructing a timer using the no-parameters constructor, the underlying thread will be a non-daemon thread by default. To make the time run on a daemon thread you can use the `Timer`'s constructor:

```java
Timer timer = new Timer(true); // a timer with a daemon thread.
```