# How starter-web prevent spring-boot exit?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

When using spring-boot-starter-web, The spring-boot application won't exit after startup.

And with Jetbrain IDEA, There is an icon show spring-boot start up finished:

[image]

[image]

But if I using :

```java
public static void main ( String[] args ){
    SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    Thread.sleep(Long.MAX_VALUE);
}
```

Or

```java
public class MyRunner implements ApplicationRunner{
    public void run() {
        Thread.sleep(Long.MAX_VALUE);
    }
}
```

Can let spring-boot keep running but the IDEA icon will loading forever, So that must be different way compare with starter-web.

Update1: And those two method will cause SpringBootTest wait forever

Question: What's the code that spring-boot-starter-web prevent spring-boot exit ?

Comment: You are running your code in embedded tomcat so it is natural to NOT to exit. You are simply using web server.

Comment: @Gurkanİlleez My application don't need seb server. This question is talking about how to achive same result without starter-web

Comment: It is not clear what your goal is. You want an application running until you cancel it's execution, but not in a web server? As if it were a simple Java application?

Comment: Also see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2213340/what-is-a-daemon-thread-in-java/2213348#2213348

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To answer the question

> What's the code that spring-boot-starter-web prevent spring-boot exit

spring-boot-web creates web server beans, that use non-daemon  listener threads (as you want them to be alive and running to waiting for incoming connections and handle them).

This makes your code reach end of your `main` method, however JVM does not exit, as it has non-daemon threads running.

If you want to keep your application alive, you'd need to do the same - the simplest way would be to e.g. create a Thread in a bean like @Slongtong has suggested.

Comment: Thanks with that. You point the most confusion: "main exit" with some test. I figure out the mechanism: Main will exit, that will let idea know application booted. And using a undemon thread to "stuck" the jvm, And event main exit, Springboot still working. And I can do what ever in the runner

Answer (score 2):

I don't know, what is a reason, but without webserver, you can prevent shutdown only if any other thread still active (non-daemon thread). Infinite loop in another thread will prevent program exit.

```
package com.example.demo;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.context.ConfigurableApplicationContext;

@SpringBootApplication
public class DemoApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("main started");
        new Thread(() -> {
            System.out.println("thread started");
            ConfigurableApplicationContext context = SpringApplication.run(DemoApplication.class, args);
            while (true) {
                System.out.println(context);
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(1000L);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                }
            }
        }).start();
        System.out.println("main finished");
    }



}
```

output example

```
    main started
    main finished
    thread started

    .   ____          _            __ _ _
    /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
    ( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
    \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
    '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
    =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
    :: Spring Boot ::                (v2.6.7)

    2022-06-24 22:34:31.648  INFO 8084 --- [       Thread-1] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Starting application using Java 1.8.0_312 on DESKTOP with PID 8084 (started by user in C:\Users\user\IdeaProjects\demo)
    2022-06-24 22:34:31.650  INFO 8084 --- [       Thread-1] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : No active profile set, falling back to 1 default profile: "default"
    2022-06-24 22:34:31.985  INFO 8084 --- [       Thread-1] org.quartz.impl.StdSchedulerFactory      : Using default implementation for ThreadExecutor
    2022-06-24 22:34:31.991  INFO 8084 --- [       Thread-1] org.quartz.core.SchedulerSignalerImpl    : Initialized Scheduler Signaller of type: class org.quartz.core.SchedulerSignalerImpl
    2022-06-24 22:34:31.991  INFO 8084 --- [       Thread-1] org.quartz.core.QuartzScheduler          : Quartz Scheduler v.2.3.2 created.
    2022-06-24 22:34:31.991  INFO 8084 --- [       Thread-1] org.quartz.simpl.RAMJobStore             : RAMJobStore initialized.
    2022-06-24 22:34:31.992  INFO 8084 --- [       Thread-1] org.quartz.core.QuartzScheduler          : Scheduler meta-data: Quartz Scheduler (v2.3.2) 'quartzScheduler' with instanceId 'NON_CLUSTERED'
    Scheduler class: 'org.quartz.core.QuartzScheduler' - running locally.
    NOT STARTED.
    Currently in standby mode.
    Number of jobs executed: 0
    Using thread pool 'org.quartz.simpl.SimpleThreadPool' - with 10 threads.
    Using job-store 'org.quartz.simpl.RAMJobStore' - which does not support persistence. and is not clustered.

    2022-06-24 22:34:31.992  INFO 8084 --- [       Thread-1] org.quartz.impl.StdSchedulerFactory      : Quartz scheduler 'quartzScheduler' initialized from an externally provided properties instance.
    2022-06-24 22:34:31.992  INFO 8084 --- [       Thread-1] org.quartz.impl.StdSchedulerFactory      : Quartz scheduler version: 2.3.2
    2022-06-24 22:34:31.992  INFO 8084 --- [       Thread-1] org.quartz.core.QuartzScheduler          : JobFactory set to: org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.SpringBeanJobFactory@501627dc
    2022-06-24 22:34:32.009  INFO 8084 --- [       Thread-1] o.s.s.quartz.SchedulerFactoryBean        : Starting Quartz Scheduler now
    2022-06-24 22:34:32.010  INFO 8084 --- [       Thread-1] org.quartz.core.QuartzScheduler          : Scheduler quartzScheduler_$_NON_CLUSTERED started.
    2022-06-24 22:34:32.015  INFO 8084 --- [       Thread-1] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Started application in 0.601 seconds (JVM running for 1.051)
    org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext@74ed4e3, started on Fri Jun 24 22:34:31 MSK 2022
    org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext@74ed4e3, started on Fri Jun 24 22:34:31 MSK 2022
    org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext@74ed4e3, started on Fri Jun 24 22:34:31 MSK 2022
and so on...
```

only 1 dependency (just random starter, not web, quartz not required here)

```
org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-quartz
```

just infinite loop in **non-daemon thread**...

Comment: Thanks. That's solve my question.