# Why RecursiveAction compute() not endless?

Tags: java

I try to understand ForkJoinPool. I actually don't understand what the `fork` method does wihout `join` and end condition.
If `fork` sends a task to be executed in a queue, then why doesn't this code run endlessly?

```
import java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool;
import java.util.concurrent.RecursiveAction;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ForkJoinPool pool = new ForkJoinPool();
        pool.invoke(new Test());
    }

    static class Test extends RecursiveAction {

        @Override
        protected void compute() {
            System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName());
            Test test = new Test();
            test.fork();
        }
    }
}
```

The result is always different.

Second question: What happens if you call self `fork` inside a compute?

```
@Override
protected void compute() {
      System.out.println(1);
      fork();
}
```

Compute will be called 1 or 2 times.

Or this:

```
protected void compute() {
      System.out.println(1);
      fork();
      join();
}
```

Compute will called many times and then stops.

Answer (score 3):

It *does* run endlessly, but they are [daemon threads](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2213340/what-is-a-daemon-thread-in-java) which don't prevent the JVM from shutting down, so they shutdown after the main thread is done, i.e. immediately. Put an infinite loop to stop the main thread from finishing, and you'll see your task go infinitely.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    ForkJoinPool pool = new ForkJoinPool();
    pool.invoke(new Test());
    while (true) {}
}

static class Test extends RecursiveAction {

    @Override
    protected void compute() {
        System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName());
        Test test = new Test();
        test.fork();
    }
}
```

Comment: Instead of an infinite loop, something like `Thread.sleep(Long.MAX_VALUE);` would also do, without burning a CPU core…

Comment: Ok, thanks, and why second code not endless? compute() executed 1 or 2 times