# How to stop a Java thread without an exit flag

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency

My M(Non)WE is as follows:

```
public class SOQuestion1 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ProducerThread producerThread1 = new ProducerThread();
        ProducerThread producerThread2 = new ProducerThread();
        
        ControllerThread1 controllerThread1 = 
                new ControllerThread1(producerThread1);
        
        controllerThread1.start();
        
        ControllerThread2 controllerThread2 = 
                new ControllerThread2(producerThread2);
        
        controllerThread2.start();
    }
}

class ProducerThread extends Thread {
    
    @Override
    public void run() {
        while (true);
    }
}

class ControllerThread1 extends Thread {
    
    private final ProducerThread producerThread;
    
    ControllerThread1(ProducerThread producerThread) {
        this.producerThread = producerThread;
    }
    
    @Override
    public void run() {
        producerThread.start();
        System.out.println("Started ControllerThread1.");
        
        try {
            producerThread.join(2000);
            
            Thread.sleep(2000);
            producerThread.interrupt();
        } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
        
        System.out.println("Joined ControllerThread1.");
    }
}

class ControllerThread2 extends Thread {
    
    private final ProducerThread producerThread;
    
    ControllerThread2(ProducerThread producerThread) {
        this.producerThread = producerThread;
    }
    
    @Override
    public void run() {
        producerThread.start();
        System.out.println("Started ControllerThread2.");
        
        try {
            Thread.sleep(2000);
            producerThread.interrupt();
        } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
        
        System.out.println("Joined ControllerThread2.");
    }
}
```

It outputs:

```
Started ControllerThread1.
Started ControllerThread2.
Joined ControllerThread2.
Joined ControllerThread1.
```

... and the producer threads remain running.

Here is, however, a constraint: since my future producer thread will load data from internet, there is not telling how fast the server will respond, and so, I cannot rely on flags in the producer threads.

Is there a way to solve this issue without using the thread continuation flags.?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "thread continuation flags"? Is this a built in mechanism of Java or something you create in your code?

Comment: Basically, I meant to say that a boolean flag in an infinite thread loop is not feasible. My producer thread will call a method that blocks indefinitely in the worst case.

Comment: I would use non-blocking IO for the producer thread, this way you can use whatever thread sync you prefer.

Comment: This might not really be a solution to your requirement "I cannot rely on flags in the producer threads", but for the issue in your example that your producer thread remain running, if you want to interrupt a thread, you need to allow the thread to be interrupted. instead of `while(true)` it should be `while(!Thread.isInterrupted())`

Comment: @BIBOOnation Nice one, but that doesn’t meet my requirements.

Comment: @cyberbrain Could you elaborate on what you mean about non-blocking IO? How about an answer?

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot give you a ready-made answer now, as I'm not frequently using that myself. But what I meant was to use calls in the `java.nio` package instead of `java.io` (if you use vanilla Java) or make use of frameworks like Spring WebFlux.

Comment: Pardon my poor understanding, but are you asking how to terminate the `ProducerThread`s once `ControllerThread1` and `ControllerThread2` have terminated?

Comment: @Abra, no poor understanding. You got it completely right.

Comment: If you’re downloading via HTTP(S), you may want to consider using [java.net.http.HttpClient](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.net.http/java/net/http/HttpClient.html), whose `send` method can be interrupted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Very simple. Make the `ProducerThread`s [daemon thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2213340/what-is-a-daemon-thread-in-java)s. By default, they are not. In the below code I simply added two lines that explicitly set the created `ProducerThread`s as daemon threads.

```java
public class SOQuestion1 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ProducerThread producerThread1 = new ProducerThread();
        producerThread1.setDaemon(true); // ADDED
        ProducerThread producerThread2 = new ProducerThread();
        producerThread2.setDaemon(true); // ADDED

        ControllerThread1 controllerThread1 = new ControllerThread1(producerThread1);
        controllerThread1.start();

        ControllerThread2 controllerThread2 = new ControllerThread2(producerThread2);
        controllerThread2.start();
    }
}

class ProducerThread extends Thread {

    @Override
    public void run() {
        while (true)
            ;
    }
}

class ControllerThread1 extends Thread {
    private final ProducerThread producerThread;

    ControllerThread1(ProducerThread producerThread) {
        this.producerThread = producerThread;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        producerThread.start();
        System.out.println("Started ControllerThread1.");
        try {
            producerThread.join(2000);
            Thread.sleep(2000);
            producerThread.interrupt();
        }
        catch (InterruptedException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
        System.out.println("Joined ControllerThread1.");
    }
}

class ControllerThread2 extends Thread {
    private final ProducerThread producerThread;

    ControllerThread2(ProducerThread producerThread) {
        this.producerThread = producerThread;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        producerThread.start();
        System.out.println("Started ControllerThread2.");
        try {
            Thread.sleep(2000);
            producerThread.interrupt();
        }
        catch (InterruptedException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
        System.out.println("Joined ControllerThread2.");
    }
}
```

Here is the output when I run the above code:

```
Started ControllerThread1.
Started ControllerThread2.
Joined ControllerThread2.
Joined ControllerThread1.
```

After the last line of output is displayed, the JVM terminates.

Comment: Exactly what I was searching for, thanks!