# Why a child thread is not stopping

Tags: java, multithreading

I have  a following simple multithreading program.I expected that `child thread` won't either start or finish after  the main thread has ended but to my surprise I could see that printing of `##Child thread I=` is is never ending.

It looks like that I am missing something very basic. Can someone please point out why the child thread is still executing even after the parent thread is finished ?

```
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        System.out.println("hello");
        new Thread(new Runnable()
        {
            int i = 0;
            public void run()
            {
                while (true)
                {
                    i++;
                    System.out.println("##Child thread i="+ i + "=th= "+ Thread.currentThread().getName());
                }

            }
        }).start();
        System.out.println("Main thread = "+ Thread.currentThread().getName());
    }
```

Comment: This is relevant: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2213340/what-is-a-daemon-thread-in-java

Comment: The thread you spawned is a *non-daemon* thread and therefore keeps the JVM alive. Also, a "parent" thread terminating does not affect any spawned "child" threads.

Comment: Rather than address `Thread` class directly, use `ExecutorService` to execute your `Runnable` object. To end the executor service, use (a) try-with-resources syntax, (b) the `close` method, or (c) the boilerplate code given in the Javadoc.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From scratch, a `Thread` in Java does not know about its parent `Thread`, so it will never notice that that parent dies.

By the way, a parent `Thread` do not know about its children either …

Of course, you can have a list of child `Thread`s in the parent:

```java
…
final List<Thread> children = new ArrayList<>();
final var thread = new Thread( task );
children.add( thread );
thread.start();
…
```

And you can have a reference to the parent in the child:

```java
public final class Action implement Runnable
{
  private final Thread m_Parent;
  private final Runnable m_Task;

  public Action( final Thread parent, final Runnable task )
  {
    m_Parent = parent;
    m_Task = task;
  }

  @Override
  public final void run()
  {
    while( m_Parent.isAlive )
    {
      m_Task.run();
    }
  }
}
```

But as said: out-of-the-box, there is no such reference.

Consequently, any Non-Daemon thread runs until it will come to an end, or until it will be interrupted (or someone kills the JVM – or the machine that executes the JVM). And even after being interrupted, the `Thread` may continue – it can just ignore the interruption.

At the opposite, a daemon thread dies automatically after the last Non-Daemon thread in the current JVM has died.

So for *your sample*, make your thread a deamon (`Thread::setDaemon` with argument `true`), and it will die with the main thread.

The `Action` class above provides a very, very basic example on how you can let a child know whether the parent is dead. It works only for tasks that terminates after one execution and have to be called repeatedly. As said: very very basic!